# How to avoid this type of path redundancy in Vue router?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

So, as usually we do like this for routing.

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/store',
    component: Dashboard
},
{
    path: '/store/products',
    component: ProductsView
},
{
    path: '/store/products/add',
    component: ProductsAddView
},
]
```

Here I'm writing the path `/store` every time. Is there any way to write this beginning of the path once?

I want to tell router, if you find `/products or /products/add` after `/store` then render those views. Every time not writing the whole path `/store/products`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Nested Routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) for Vue Router.

Example from the Vue Router documentation adapted to your use case:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { 
      path: '/store/', 
      component: Dashboard,
      children: [
        {
          // route /store/products
          path: 'products',
          component: ProductsView
          children: [
            // route /store/products/add
            path: 'add',
            component: ProductsAddView
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/) of the Vue Router documentation for a live example.